# split XML file by elements

Tags: java, xml, xslt

This is similar question with few differences :

[Split XML file into multiple files based on a threshold value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433529/split-xml-file-into-multiple-files-based-on-a-threshold-value)

My root element is called stores, and elements to split are called store. And I want to do this from java with xsl or without, here is my java code which I used to trigger the xsl :

```
public void transform(String transformator, File source, String destination) {
    try {    
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(transformatorLocation));

        try {
            transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(source), "UTF-8")), new StreamResult(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(destination), "UTF-8")));
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File is missing");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I've tried both solutions in this question, but they both produce erros, one is :

> ERROR:  'Unsupported XSL element 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform:for-each-group''
>       javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported XSL element 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform:for-each-group'

Other is that style sheet can't be compiled.

What I try to accomplish ? Pass argument to java class how many stores do I want in one file, and split it into n parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that `for-each-group` is an XSLT 2.0 construct. The default XSLT processors in java do not yet support XSLT 2.0.

You either need to stick with XSLT 1.0, or find a XSLT processor that does 2.0, and use that instead (for example, [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/)).